# Add an action in the Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am newly using the Scene builder and I would like to add a click action to a button. However, I don't see the dropdown menu to add the click action. I am in the Mac OS platform and using the IntelliJ. The screenshot is provided,

[image]

The `sample.fxml` file is provided below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane cache="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="445.0" prefWidth="597.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnn" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="33.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

I redownloaded the installed the scene builder and this doesn't solve the issue. How do I add an action to the Scene builder?

Comment: As can be seen, the drop-down menu is not available for selecting the action.

Comment: Have you specified the controller for the root element, made sure it's accessible to scenebuilder and made sure that the event handler method either takes no parameter of the javafx action event, not the awt one?

Comment: How do you specify the controller in the root element? It's takes the `import javafx.event.ActionEvent;` 

Do you mean pane as the root element?

Comment: Okay, I see no reference of the  `MyController.java` in the `sample.fxml` file. I guess this is the issue. Though I still don't know how do I add the controller file in the FXML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you must keep in mind while working with `Scenebuilder`.

1. Specify the controller in the root element. It can be done as given below. 
   [image]
2. Without specifying controller, you won't get any drop down for selecting the action. You first need to specify controller. Don't proceed furthur, if you haven't.
3. Below given is the correct way to create a method for button action.

   @FXML private void buttonAction(ActionEvent event) {
     //your code
   }
4. Before looking for **onAction** drop down menu. Make sure you have created the method (that you're looking for in the drop down) in the controller class.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually edit the `sample.fxml` file to have the drop-down menu available.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane cache="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="445.0" prefWidth="597.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.MainController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnn" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="33.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onPress" text="Button" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

The other answer is informing that we can have the `Document` menu to set the controller which I don't have here.

[image]

Solution

Open the `sample.xml` file in the Scene Builder app than IntelliJ Interface and the issue is solved. It seems there might be a bug in the IntelliJ or a compatibility issue.

This is the first time I use the JavaFX, so not sure what is the exact issue, but, I find a way to walk though.

Comment: How can you not have the document menu?. Which version of `Scene Builder` are you using?

Comment: If you open the `sample.xml` file in the `SceneBuilder` app, it works pretty fine than to open in the `IntelliJ`. I believe the issue is with the `IntelliJ` UI

Comment: Yeah. That may be the problem, I guess.